# Initial value for textbox doesnot show after I adding jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display initial value which selected from the database for the date text field.Im adding a date from jquery date picker. After I adding the jquery code Initial value does not show..Can anyone suggest me an answer? Thank you !

here is my jquery code

```
<script src="JDate/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="JDate/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="JDate/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="JDate/demos/demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#birthday_text" ).datepicker();

        $( "#birthday_text" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );

    });

</script>
```

here is my textbox code

```
<input name="birthday_text" type="text" class="textfield" id="birthday_text" autocomplete="off" value="0000-00-00" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the default date when you attach the date picker as so:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#birthday_text" ).datepicker( {defaultDate:"0000-00-00",dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HTcS/) with demo

**Update**: Since you say that the "defaultDate" parameter is giving you problems, try this alternative:

```
  $( "#birthday_text" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" } );
  $( "#birthday_text" ).val('0000-00-00');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qZKj/) for alternative.

Comment: @Lahiru_B then you are doing something wrong. The JSFiddle works just fine. Did you check it?

Comment: I did it as you said but it sasy syntax errors that paramete doesnt take like defaultDate:"0000-00-00"

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the default date with the options when you're setting the datepicker up.  Check out their docs on default date:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate.  Also, there is a chance that the datepicker control won't let you use 0000-00-00 since it isn't a valid date.  Have you tried with something other than all zeros?

Comment: Yes actually I want to view a selected date from the database at initial state.Then I need to update that date from choosing a date from datepicker

Comment: Yeah, using that defaultDate option I linked should do everything you need.